# jquery change display doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a div to become visible, when a "button" is pressed. 
Here is the html that represents the button:

```
<span id='dl' class='btn' data-app-id=''>DOWNLOAD<br/>FREE</span></div>
```

Here is the html of the div in its initial stage before the button is pressed.

```
<div class='box' id='dlbox' style='display:none'>
    <div class='title'>
        <span class='text'>Confirm install</span>
        <span id='x1' class='x'></span>
    </div>
    <p>Click to install </p>
    <p><?php echo "<span style='font-weight:bold'>$app->appName</span>"; ?></p>
</div>​
```

The jquery is this:

```
$("#dl").live("click", function() {
    $("#dlblank").toggle();
    $("#dlbox").toggle();
});​
```

The css of the div when "toggled":

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #4d0404;
    opacity: none;
    z-index: 9001;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 7px black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I think its due to opacity: none;  , since I guess toggle only changes display property not opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to use show and hide instead toggle as it is a bit clearer what is going on. I would also put the disply none in the jquery too.

```
$('#dlbox').css('display':'none');   
$(document).ready(function() {   
       $("#dl").live("click", function(){
            $("#dlbox").show()
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you've missed opening `<div>` tag here

```
<div><span id='dl' class='btn' data-app-id=''>DOWNLOAD<br/>FREE</span></div>
```

Otherwise, your code works good and the only reason that your code can't work for you can be that you are using old version of jQuery(1.2.6 for example) and live function isn't defined here.

I've created jsfiddle and you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/9wLjL/

Answer (score 1):

You have an markup error. A closing `</div>` without opening. On the first line

Next, you might want to stop using `.bind()` it is deprecated. You should use `.on()` instead.

```
$("#dl").on("click", function(){
    $("#dlblank").toggle();
$("#dlbox").toggle();});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3uEWr/) <sub>without the `div`</sub>

Comment: I  have a problem with the button. It works half of the time.. what might be the problem. might it be not binded..or is there an event clash?

Answer (score 1):

did `$('#dl').click(function(){ /*....*/ }` works.